# Deepin movie doesn't work in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I installed `deepin-movie` from the official repository but it's not working, when I'm openning it from terminal I get these errors:

```
probeHwdecInterop "" ""
"dtkwidget" can not find qm files
"deepin-movie" can not find qm files
configPath "/home/mohammad/.config/deepin/deepin-movie/config.conf"
create config "/home/mohammad/.config/deepin/deepin-movie/config.conf"
[1]    10647 segmentation fault (core dumped)  deepin-movie
```

This is the output of `deepin-movie --version`:

```
probeHwdecInterop "" ""
deepin-movie 3.2.7
```

I tried to install `deepin-movie-reborn` with apt but it says unable to locate.

Comment: wild guess and at your own risk

 sudo apt install qt5-default

Comment: @pierrely Thanks, it's already installed.